# Extend the Fourier transform over $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: harmonic-analysis

Using Plancherel theorem, we have that the Fourier transform is an isometry over $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$. But anyway. In my course it's written that Plancherel theorem is extremely important since it allow us to prolonge the fourier transform from $S(\mathbb R^n)$ (i.e. the schwarz space) to $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$. Indeed, $$\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(x)e^{2\pi i x\cdot \xi}dx$$
doesn't converge in the absolute sense if $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$. However, given such $f$, we simply pick a sequence $\{f_n\}\subset S(\mathbb R^n)$ (that exist by density of $S(\mathbb R^n)$ in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$) with $$f_n\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow } f$$ in the $L^2$ sense. Then, using Plancherel's theorem, $\{\hat f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a cauchy sequence in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$, and hence we can defined $$\hat f=\lim_{n\to\infty }\hat f_n$$
using the fact that $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ is complete.

**My questions are the following:**

1) Finally, when $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ does $\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(x)e^{2\pi ix\cdot \xi}dx$  exist or not ?

2) And does $\hat f$ that is the limit of the $\{\hat f_n\}$ is given by $$\hat f(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(x)e^{2\pi ix\cdot \xi}dx.$$

I'm a little bit lost in all that.

Comment: Formula 1) only works for a dense subset, while the Plancherel transform is defined (by extension) for the entire space. However, it is customary to write the formula on the right hand side of 1) rather than using another symbol to represent the Plancherel transform. Formula 2) is only strictly valid if the left hand side is in the aforementioned dense subset.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the sense of Lebesgue integration, the integral defining the Fourier transform of $f$ makes sense if and only if $f \in L^1$. That's easy to see: the integral has to converge absolutely, and the modulus of the integrand is just $|f|$. Since $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \setminus L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is nonempty, there are $L^2$ functions for which the integral does not converge. One example would be $x^{-2/3} 1_{[1,\infty)}(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. I don't really understand what you mean here. If you mean "if I Schwarz-approximate the FT of an $L^1$ function, do I get the FT in the sense of Lebesgue integration?", the answer is yes. (If it weren't, this Schwarz trick would be awful.) If you mean "is the Schwarz limit of the FT of an $L^2$ function the FT of it *in the sense of distribution theory*?", the answer is again yes. (This means that $\langle \hat{f},\hat{g} \rangle = C \langle f,g \rangle$ for any Schwarz function $g$, where $C$ is a constant depending only on the FT normalization you are using.) It is in this sense that we identify this Schwarz-approximation limit as "the FT" of a function for which the FT integral doesn't converge. I think in pretty much any other sense the answer to this question is no.

Comment: My question for 2) would be does $\int _{-\infty }^\infty f(x)e^{2\pi inx\cdot \xi}dx$ will converge to $\hat f(\xi)$ in the $L^2$ sense ?

Comment: @MathBeginner If $f \not \in L^1 \cap L^2$, no. It has to be in $L^1$ for the integral to converge at all, and it has to be in $L^2$ for it to be able to converge in $L^2$ (since $L^2$ is complete). If $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$, I think it works (intuitively it must because the FT is unique in the sense of distribution theory).

Comment: @Ian: I think what Mathbeginner want's to says is that if $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^2)$, then $\int_{|x|\leq N}f(x)e^{2\pi in x\cdot \xi}dx$ will converge in the $L^2$ sense, and that we can define it's limit as the FT of $f$. And I think that this is true. But the fact that the $\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{|x|\leq N}f(x)e^{2\pi in x\cdot \xi}dx=\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(x)e^{2\pi in x\cdot \xi}dx$ required indeed $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ (I think)

Comment: @MSE The actual integral definition of the FT makes sense iff $f$ is in $L^1$. I didn't see anything about cutting off to $[-N,N]$ here, all I saw was using Schwarz approximations.

Comment: To all: I answered to try to clarify the situation for MSE and MathBeginner, I hope it will be fine, and let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: @Surb: Could you answer to my question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846755/is-fourier-series-l2

Comment: @MathBeginner: please, don't do that in the futur, it's not a good attitude.

Answer (score 0):

**To clarify the situation**

Using your definition, the Fourier transform is defined as following
\begin{align*}
\mathfrak F: \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)&\longrightarrow \mathscr F(\mathbb R^n):=\{f:\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \mathbb R\mid f\text{ is a function}\}\\
f&\longmapsto \hat f
\end{align*}
where \begin{eqnarray}\mathfrak F(f)(\xi)=\hat f(\xi)=\int_{-\infty }^\infty f(x)e^{2\pi ix\cdot \xi}\mathrm d x.\tag{1}\end{eqnarray}

You can also define
 \begin{align*}
\mathcal  F: L^1(\mathbb R^n)&\longrightarrow  \mathscr F(\mathbb R^n)\\
f&\longmapsto \hat f
\end{align*}
 but this definition is less interesting than the previous one since $\mathcal F$ will not be extendable to $L^2$ as easily (the only way to extend it to $L^2$ is to consider the restriction to function with compact support, but I'm not even sure if it's really enough). Anyway. Now, what you said (and your arguments are true) is that you can prolonge $\mathfrak F$ on $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ using density of $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ and completness of $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$.

This doesn't mean that for $f\in L^2$ unspecified it's Fourier transform is going to be given by $(1)$. It just mean that you can defined \begin{align*}
\tilde{\mathfrak F}:L^2(\mathbb R^n)&\longrightarrow \mathscr F(\mathbb R^n)\\
f&\longmapsto \tilde{\mathfrak F}(f):=\lim_{n\to \infty }\mathfrak F(f_n),\quad f_n\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)
\end{align*}
such that $\left.\tilde{\mathfrak F}\right|_{\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)}=\mathfrak F$. Notice that $$f=\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n,$$ in the $L^2-$sense. Then $\tilde{\mathfrak F}$ is called the prolongement of $\mathfrak F$ and is well defined by the argument you said.

Therefore, for $f\in L^2$ unspecified, if $f$ is in $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$, then $\tilde{\mathfrak F}(f):=\hat f$ in the sense of $(1)$, and if $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)\backslash \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$, then $$\tilde{\mathfrak F}(f):=\lim_{n\to \infty }\hat f_n,$$
where $$\hat f_n(\xi)=\int_{|x|\leq n}f(x)e^{2\pi i x\cdot \xi}\mathrm d x$$ and the limit is of course taken in the $L^2-$sense.

Maybe you can notice that it's the same as $g:]0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $g(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. You can prolonge $g$ on $0$ mean that there is $\hat g:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ s.t. $\hat g|_{]0,1]}=g$ and $\hat g(0)=\lim_{n\to \infty }g(x)$, but it doesn't mean that $g(0)=0$ (since $g$ is not defined at $0$).

Comment: Ok, I see much better. But for this prolongement $\tilde F$ could I says that $\tilde F(f)=0$ when $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)\backslash  \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ ? we also would have that $\tilde F|_{\mathbb S(\mathbb R^n)}=F$, no ?

Comment: This is not a prolongement ! By "prolongement" we mean in the sense that $$\tilde {\mathfrak F}(f)=\tilde {\mathfrak F}(\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty }\tilde {\mathfrak F}(f_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty }\mathfrak F(f_n).$$ Or if you prefer, "prolongement by continuity" since in a metric space, the continuity and sequential continuity are equivalent.

Comment: I think this is a bit muddled, though it is encapsulating some important points. I think the biggest problem is that @MathBeginner appears to believe that the integral definition of the FT is *the* definition of the FT. It's not. We first define the FT that way for $f \in \mathcal{S}$ (note that $\mathcal{S} \subset L^1$). Then we *extend* it by duality to $\mathcal{S}'$, using the identity $\langle \hat{d},\hat{f} \rangle = C \langle d,f \rangle$.

Comment: (Cont.) Here $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is the dual pairing between tempered distributions and Schwarz functions, $d$ is a tempered distribution, $f$ is a Schwarz function, and $C$ is a normalization constant. This mapping on $\mathcal{S}'$ is "the FT". The topology here is that of pointwise convergence of tempered distributions. If we want a different topology, we restrict the domain and proceed accordingly.

Comment: @Ian: I think it's a good answer :) It's not confusing and clear (+1)

Comment: @user330587 I think it would be better to take the initial definition to just map into $\mathcal{S}$ rather than into $\mathscr{F}$ (which incidentally is not standard notation). Then extending the domain extends the codomain (which should be no surprise).

Comment: @Ian: I totally agree with you on this point. I first wanted to map $\mathfrak F$ into $\mathcal S$, but then, to justify that the prolongement map to $L^2$ was a little bit complicate, that's why I prefer to map into $\mathscr F(\mathbb R^n)$. In fact it's a consequence of plancherel, but I prefer to be prudent an take things more "simple". For the notation $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R^n}$, it has to many exposant, that's why I prefer using $\mathscr F(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)=:\mathscr F(\mathbb R^n)$. But I don't think that it's an unusual notation.